# Shell Script not going to next step after submitting a streaming python job

Tags: python, bash, docker, shell, sh

My existing shell script is trying to:

1. Start a docker,
2. Change the permission of the Python file in it,
3. Run that while looped (streaming) python job in docker (Not wait for it),
4. Run a python job outside (in the local machine) which will feed data to the docker python job for which it waits.

#!/bin/bash

```
clear
docker run -d -v /home/ubuntu/Downloads/docker_work/test_py_app/app:/workspace/app -p 8881:8888 -p 5002:5002 --gpus all --name pytorch nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:server-v1.0 tail -f /dev/null

sudo docker exec -it pytorch chmod 777 /workspace/server/server.py

sudo docker exec -it pytorch python /workspace/server/server.py

python /home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/test/pipeline/client.py

exit
```

If the two python programs' runs are put into two different shell, it works perfectly fine, but the problem with the existing piece is, the shell gets stuck at server python file run inside docker. How can I fire it in an async fashion? So that, immediately after triggering the first python job, it goes and starts the local machine's python job?

Comment: Try run them with `--detach` option.. `sudo docker exec -d pytorch python /workspace/server/server.py`

Comment: And how to do the same for local python job? So that the shell triggers everything and finishes itself?

Comment: Add a space followed by `&` to the end of last command.

Comment: Do you have a custom Dockerfile?  That can start `FROM` the pytorch image, `COPY` your application code in, and `RUN chmod` if required; then you can `docker run` the resulting image directly, application source included, without needing debugging tools like `docker exec`.

Comment: @AakashBasu add ampersand at the end of command on localhost... You can also create a service. check: https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux/ 
.. Or use supervisor solution https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps

Comment: @DavidMaze I do not have a custom Dockerfile as it is taken from an existing NVIDIA Pytorch image. I just ran that, edited, added the necessary libs, added my codes and committed to get a ready plug & play version for N number of uses going fwd. Is exec not the right way to use in production in the docker world?

Comment: `docker exec` is a debugging tool.  `docker commit` is an emergency last-ditch you-have-no-other-choice debugging tool.  (If there's a security issue in PyTorch in a year, and you _must_ rebuild your custom image, will you remember exactly what libraries and code you added to rebuild it?)